# Android: MVVM: Save State Of RecyclerView OR Save Fragment State

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

In short: I am getting data with a retrofit call and displaying it in a recyclerView. However when I navigate away the data is destroyed: that means that upon going back to the fragment the call is made again and new data is fetched and displayed in the recyclerView.

Ideally I would like to receive the data, display it, navigate away, come back and have the same data there. Perfect would be to have a pull to refresh function or just button that will refresh the list when the user presses it.

Otherwise, the recycler would be constantly displaying new data when I navigate to some other fragment. And that is not good.

Any ideas or suggestions would help. Thank you...

P.S. The data is fetched in the viewModel, which is then observed in the fragment.

Comment: You using navigation or fragment transaction to show Fragment?

Comment: I am using Jetpack Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

"The data is fetched in the viewModel, which is then observed in the fragment."

case 1:
If the viewmodel belongs to the fragment , saving data may have to be done to a database table and retrieved from database every time the fragment attaches itself and load the recycler.

case 2: 
If the viewmodel belongs to the activity, viewmodel itself can be shared to the fragment.

Comment: The viewModel belongs to the Fragment. So I guess, I should opt for case 1. Save the data/retrieve when I need it. Thanks for the idea. If you have any useful Kotlin examples on how to save to/retrieve from Realm, that would be great! Thanks once again.

Comment: I have not tried a hand on Realm. If you  think of using Room Database, try this link as a source: https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I'll give it a try and post the results, if I can make anything out of it.

Comment: @SamirRamic did that work? I am trying to work on similar path, the challenge that comes in is , when we change fragment and get back to original, the livedata has the last pulled paginated list which starts coming at the top whereas it should stay at its place. I am trying to see a clean architectural way of doing this.

Comment: @89n3ur0n As I remember I had to store the data and but also use OnSaveInstanceState and On RestoreInstanceState. I believe that saving the data and refreshing it (via API call) only when you need is definitely the right direction. You could also look into on Resume and try that one out as well. Hope it helps. Btw. I ended up using Room which in hindsight is the right choice with MVVM.